# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '('loadstop').subscribe') on Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm using InAppBrowser in ionic, and I want to checked if it is redirected to a specific url should close the browser.

```
 const browser = this.iab.create(href);
        browser.on('loadstop').subscribe(event => {
          if (event.url == urlSuccessurl) {
            browser.close();    
          }
      });
```

However, I faced the following error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'browser.on('loadstop').subscribe') —
```

Note: I have installed InAppBrowser using Capacitor

Comment: Shall I know the imports you added. Because, through capacitor we can add both cordova and capacitor plugins. Both the cordova IAB and capacitor IAB are supported in capacitor.

Comment: import { InAppBrowser } from '@awesome-cordova-plugins/in-app-browser/ngx';